# PuTTy command in PHP doesn't work, web service to restart Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, ssh, raspberry-pi, putty

I am trying to do simple web service in PHP (I use Laravel) to restart and shutdown my raspberry  pi.

I tried in my PHP service call something like this:

```
exec("putty -ssh pi@192.168.0.12 -pw myPassword -m D:\workspace\CPS\public\ssh\restart.txt");
```

In my *restart.txt* I have simple command `sudo shutdown -r now`

but when I call my web service in Advanced Rest Client Application (Chrome addon), my request is processing and never ending. In command line this works properly.

I thought that the problem is with running PuTTy directly in PHP and I do some changes and create `.bat` file with the following content:

```
echo off
putty -ssh pi@%1 -pw %2 -m %3
```

I start this batch script like this:

```
exec("D:\workspace\CPS\public\ssh\restart.bat 192.168.0.12 myPassword D:\workspace\CPS\public\ssh\restart.txt");
```

...but result is the same. I changed my web service to GET method and call service in the browser like page but nothing change.

I haven't any error/exception in log files and in console. I also checked the system log but nothing found.

Am I doing something wrong or missed something? It is possible or there is a better way to achieve this?

Currently I run it on Windows 7 and XAMPP. I will do second version for Linux in future and decide in code which command should I run depends on current environment.

**Update**
I forgot to wrote, all required users have permissions to execute files in my *(...)/ssh* directory

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
echo system("D:\workspace\CPS\public\ssh\restart.bat 192.168.0.12 myPassword D:\workspace\CPS\public\ssh\restart.txt");
```

to get output. May be you find something error.

And you need to check safe_mode options in your php.ini file (like `disable_functions` and `safe_mode_exec_dir`).

And try to use `FULL` path to your putty.exe file. Webserver work's in another directory, than your bat file.

Comment: I have system environment to PuTTY and I checked full path too. I will check your suggestions.

Comment: `echo system(...)` not return any errors.
This is my `safe_mode` lines with listed variables:
safe_mode=Off
safe_mode_exec_dir=
disable_functions=
This variables are empty. I will looking for information on this and see if I need to change something in my php.ini